# How to handle exceptions for specific controller in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a controller that handles API requests. Now I need to handle any exceptions for this controller individually i.e. convert to json/xml format, override message or add any details. Handling exceptions globally is not suitable in my case.

Today I have a KernelEvent subscriber that handles kernel.exception and detects current controller ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/nitso/828d58140104b4ea140b7714ab3214be)):

```
public function processApiException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $controllerName = $this->container->get('controller_name_converter');
    $resolver = new ControllerResolver($this->container, controllerName);
    $controller = $resolver->getController($event->getRequest());

    if ($contoller && $controller[0] instanceof JsonApiControllerInterface) {
        $this->handleApiExceptionEvent($event);
    }
}
```

So, the questions are:

- Is it a good solution to handle specific controller exceptions in that way?
- Is there any other method to get current controller (from GetResponseForExceptionEvent) other than using ControllerResolver?

Comment: have a look at this [knp university](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest2/validation-errors-test) tutorial. Make an exception listener which will only run with a pattern match on the path.

Comment: Maybe make your own exception at which point a global listener could listen for that specific type of exception.

Comment: Interesting question, and I've never done it, but could this be accomplished with a custom monolog channel?  If your controller was registered as a service and tagged with the appropriate logger?

Comment: @DevDonkey thanks for tutorial, I'll take a look at it

Comment: @Cerad specific type requires conversion from every type to specific: `try {...} catch (\Exception $e) {throw SpecificException;}` That's an ugly copypaste in every controller/action.

Comment: @RobertWade thanks for idea. A tag mechanism could be more symfony-way. I'll try to do a research.

Comment: I see.  You want to catch all exceptions from the controller.  Another approach would be to add a default value to your api routes and then just test for it in your listener.

Answer (score 0):

Well the way I know and use is

1. In the Response send the error code, both sides must know the meaning of the codes.
2. In the Response return a json like this:

   `{'success':false,'errors':[{'code':'ERROR_CODE','message':'Message here'}]}`